# Whitespace in contenteditable causes linebreak

Tags: javascript, html, css, contenteditable

When you click on the background in the following snippet, a `contenteditable` `<span>` is created. Try to write "Hello World". **The whitespace causes a linebreak.** Why ?

**How to make that the whitespaces don't cause any linebreak anymore in the contenteditable span ?**

```js
    window.onload = function() {
      var container = document.createElement("div"),
        wrapper = document.createElement("div");

      container.style.position = "absolute";
      wrapper.style.position = "relative";
      container.appendChild(wrapper);
      document.body.appendChild(container);

      window.onclick = function(e) {
        var tb = document.createElement('span');
        tb.contentEditable = true;
        tb.style.position  = 'absolute';
        tb.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
        tb.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
        wrapper.appendChild(tb);
        tb.focus();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS `white-space:pre`

> "Sequences of whitespace are preserved, lines are only broken at newline characters in the source and at `<br>` elements."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Simply add the line:

```
tb.style.whiteSpace = 'pre';
```

**E.G:**

```js
    window.onload = function() {
      var container = document.createElement("div"),
        wrapper = document.createElement("div");

      container.style.position = "absolute";
      wrapper.style.position = "relative";
      container.appendChild(wrapper);
      document.body.appendChild(container);

      window.onclick = function(e) {
        var tb = document.createElement('span');
        tb.contentEditable = true;
        tb.style.position  = 'absolute';
        tb.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
        tb.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
        tb.style.whiteSpace = 'pre'; // < here
        wrapper.appendChild(tb);
        tb.focus();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Moob ! I have a related very tricky problem here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27185427/unwanted-linebreak-in-contenteditable-div
Would you have any idea?